# How can i put click events on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

This is how I tried to call the `setState(id)` function for every option in my menu. It doesn't work. Maybe there is another way to do this properly?

I know that a function inside a function is not a good idea but I'm a newbie with jQuery and don't really know how to fix it. Thanks for the answers.

```js
function setState(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1: { break; }
    case 2: { break; }
    case 3: { break; }
    case 4: { break; }
    case 5: { break; }
    case 6: { break; }
  }   
}

$('#button-menu').find('span').each.(function(){
  $(this).on("click", (function(){
    setState($(this).data("id"))
  }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-icon" id="button-menu">
  <span data-id="1">Option1</span>
  <span data-id="2">Option2</span>
  <span data-id="3">Option3</span>
  <span data-id="4">Option4</span>
  <span data-id="5">Option5</span>
  <span data-id="6">Option6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Theres a very obvious syntax error with the `.` after `each()`. Fix that and the code you've shown works fine, although you can remove the `each()` as you don't need it at all. You should probably add some `break;` statements in your `switch` to stop the conditions falling through too.

Comment: $('#button-menu').find('span').on("click", .... ); is sufficient

Comment: Ow, that's unfortunate, because i got Syntax Error on that line and i cannot find the issue. :/

Comment: as said the each isn't needed, however, if you remove the `.` after the `each.` the code works. This looks like just a typo

Comment: Omg, thank you so much i'm so blind "." .Thanks for advices with removing the each statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that the `.` after `each` is causing a syntax error. You can see this in the console. Note that this should be the first place you check whenever some JS code does not work as you expect it to. In most browsers this can be opened by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

There are also several other things you can do to improve the logic:

- remove `find()` and just select the `#button-menu span` elements directly
- remove the `each()` entirely. You can add event handlers on a collection of elements as a group
- you don't need to wrap anonymous functions in `()`

```js
function setState(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:{
      console.log('one');
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      console.log('two');
      break;
    }
    case 3: {
      console.log('three');
      break;
    }
    case 4: {
      console.log('four');
      break;
    }
    case 5: {
      console.log('five');
      break;
    }
    case 6: {
      console.log('six');
      break;
    }
  }
}

$('#button-menu span').click(function() {
  setState($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-icon" id="button-menu">
  <span data-id="1">Option1</span>
  <span data-id="2">Option2</span>
  <span data-id="3">Option3</span>
  <span data-id="4">Option4</span>
  <span data-id="5">Option5</span>
  <span data-id="6">Option6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the .each function, because jQuery abstracts it for you...

You can simply `$('#button-menu').find('span').on('click', func...`

And jQuery will apply the event to every button that the selector returns.

Comment: The OP is using `data-id`, not the actual `id` attribute, so using `data('id')` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The more simple route to take is using **Event Delegation**. Which simply means placing a click handler on the container element and capturing all child events that bubble to the top ie. **Event Bubbling** . Quick example below :

`button-menu` is your container element in this case...

```
$("#button-menu").on('click', function(e){
    let id = $(e.target).data("id");
    setState(id);
    console.log(id);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan feel free to elaborate .
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events
https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't realise you'd attached the event handler to the `#button-menu` directly. Note that you could use jQuery's delegated `on()` signature to simplify the logic further: `$("#button-menu").on('click', 'span', function(e) { setState($(this).data('id'); });`

Answer (score 0):

remove the "." after "each" and you are fine.